# Sorting JSON string with usort - only sorting 1st two objects

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

My JSON String,

[image]

`$rs` is my array,
and I am doing,

```
while($ra[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($dno)) 
    {
        $restaurants['id']=$ra[$counter]['R_ID'];
        $restaurants['name']=$ra[$counter]['name'];

        $distancefull = distance($userlat, $userlon, $ra[$counter]['lat'], $ra[$counter]['lng'], "K");
        $restaurants['distance'] = (float)round($distancefull, 2);   

        $restaurants['contact']=$ra[$counter]['contact'];
        $restaurants['area']=$ra[$counter]['area'];
    $counter++;
    $rs[]=$restaurants;
    }
    function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        //return strcmp($a["distance"], $b["distance"]);
        return ($a["distance"] - $b["distance"]);
    }

    usort($rs, "cmp");

 return $rs;
```

then,

```
json_encode(array('Reataurants'=>$rs),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I want to sort objects by distance, but only 1st two are done.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `$rs` the result you get directly from `json_decode()`? or are you setting `$rs` to be the array at the `Restaurants` property of the object returned from the `json_decode()` call? In other word did you do `$rs = json_decode($json);` or `$json_object = json_decode($json); $rs = $json_object->Restaurants;`?

Comment: json_encode(array('Reataurants'=>$rs),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: That makes no sense.  You need to DECODE the JSON to be able to work with it.

Comment: What is $rs before usort and what is it after?

Comment: I want to sort the array, before json_encode, so might not need to decode, See the review question please.
I have added some more detail.

Comment: before is in this order (by distance): 11.39, 11.33, 7.97, 8.3...
After image is attached in the question.

Answer (score 0):

distance looks like float and not strings. Do:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a["distance"] - $b["distance"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, b-a gave desc order, and a-b gave asc but still not are all properly sorted.
8.52, 8.3, 7.97, 11.33, 11.39 is not completely sorted.

Comment: Maybe they are not floats but strings. So try: `(float)$a["distance"] - (float)$b["distance"]`

Comment: They were strings basically, I used JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK...
still same after (float)@a...

Comment: If you do `(float)$a["distance"]` on each distance and just print them. What do you get?

Comment: Then I image you do something else wrong. Can you post more code?